# Windows API Programming Startup

Tags: winapi

I want to learn windows API and PInvoke methods just like MesseageBeep in User32.dll.

Can you refer a book or a website where I can learn all of those in step by step way.

An ebook will also be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Guru.

Comment: Although I know I can't find all of them in a single book but I need something where I can find the most important ones there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with [this tutorial](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/).

For a more in-depth study, the ultimate bible of Win32 programming is [Petzold's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/157231995X)

Comment: Sir, it was a too good answer but could you please refer me a .NET tutorials or book as I'm a .NET developer and all C code goes up to my mind.


Thanks.

Comment: If you really want to learn the Win32 API you really should learn C.  It was designed to be used from C.  You can't get the P/Invoke subtleties without knowing the language.